# Cholesky factorization of semi-definite matrices in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra

I am to implement a function to do a Cholesky factorization of a semidefinite matrix in C++ and am wondering if there is an library/anything out there that is already optimized. It is to work as or similar to what is described in this:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0096300310012713

This is an example for positive definite but it doesn't work for positive semi-definite: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky.E2.80.93Banachiewicz_and_Cholesky.E2.80.93Crout_algorithms

The program must be in C++, with no C/FORTRAN libraries, (think pointy hared boss giving instructions) which means ATLAS, LAPACK, ect. are out. I have looked through MTL + Boost but theirs only works for positive definite matrices. Are there any libraries that I haven't found, or even single functions that have been written?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with Cholesky decomposition of semi definite matrices is that 1) it is not unique 2) Crout's algorithm fails.

The existence of a decomposition is usually proven non constructively, via a limiting argument (if M_n -> M, and M_n = U^t_n U_n, then ||U_n|| = ||M_n||^1/2 where ||.|| = Hilbert-Schmidt norm, and U_n is a bounded sequence. Extract a subsequence to find a limit U satisfying U^t U = M and U triangular.)

I have found that in the cases I was interested in, it was satisfactory to multiply the diagonal elements by 1 + epsilon, with epsilon small (take a few thousand times the machine epsilon) to give a perfectly acceptable decomposition.

Indeed, if M is positive semi definite, then for each epsilon > 0, M + epsilon I is definite positive.

As the scheme converges when epsilon goes to zero, you can contemplate computing the decomposition for multiple epsilons and perform a Richardson extrapolation.

As to the positive definite case, you could implement Crout's algorithm yourself (there is a sample code in Numerical Recipes), but I would highly recommend against writing it yourself, and advise using LAPACK instead.

*This may involve having your boss pay for Intel MKL if he is concerned by potentially poor implementations of LAPACK. Most of the time I heard such a speech, the rationale was "but we can't control the code, we do want to write it yourself so that we can debug it in case of a problem". Dumb argument. LAPACK is 40 years old and thoroughly tested.*

*Requiring not to use LAPACK is as silly as requiring not to use the standard library for sine, cosine and logarithms.*

Comment: Thank you for the help, I think that I may give asking for a compiler a shot on Monday, but I am not holding my breath. I am going to try and use the Eigen or MTL implementation of Crout's algorithm to do this and see how that works.

Comment: Note that for some uses, the non-unicity do not matter, for example, one application is to simulate multinornal vectors, then any solution does the trick.